# Installing Windows 8 while keeping Windows 7 installer

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I have a netbook with windows 7 installer. While the netbook(PC) is booting I can press a button and tell the netbook to install fresh new windows 7. Without losing this installer how can I install windows 8?

Comment: You would need to create a new partition on your hdd then insert a Windows 8 installation disk and install Windows 8 to that new partition.

Comment: Do what's been suggested above (I recommend booting from a Linux LiveCD/USB and running GParted for partition tinkering), and be sure not to remove the manufacturer's recovery partition that is responsible for the feature you describe.